# DynamicBlurView pod get installed, without adding it to podfile.

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

here is my pod file for my project

```
pod 'GoogleMaps', '1.13.2'
    pod 'Toast', '3.0'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'EBForeNotification'
    pod 'SwiftDate', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'Gloss'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'ObjectMapper+Realm'
    pod 'ObjectMapper'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'PopupDialog', '0.7'
    pod 'FacebookCore'
    pod 'AccountKit'
    pod 'FacebookLogin'
    pod 'AKImageCropperView'
    pod 'ABKeyboardAccessory'
    pod 'ESTabBarController-swift'
    pod 'Timberjack', :git => 'https://github.com/andysmart/Timberjack.git', :branch => 'master'
    pod 'FSPagerView', '0.5'
    pod 'Mixpanel-swift', '2.2.2'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks’
    pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Calendar', '1.2.1'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'HCSStarRatingView', '1.5'
    pod 'VIMediaCache'
```

whenever I do execute `pod install` `DynamicBlurView` get install as pod. 
I have no clue why DynamicBlurView is getting install. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: may be some pod you try to install may use this pod so it will install in your pod file

Comment: found it. `pod 'PopupDialog', '0.7'`. I changed its version to `0.6`. thanks for the hint.

Comment: If this happens again, check this: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3611 It might highlight which on is adding an "surprise" pod.

Comment: @Larme thank you for link. this is very helpful.